# Python threading timer initial daemon

Tags: python, multithreading, daemon

This code is not working......

```
self._thread = threading.Timer(interval=2, 
                               function=self._sendRequestState, 
                               args=(self._lockState,), 
                               daemon=True).start()
```

So I should write down like this..

```
self._thread = threading.Timer(interval=2, 
                               function=self._sendRequestState, 
                               args=(self._lockState,))
self._thread.daemon = True
self._thread.start()
```

But the `Timer` class has `Thread.__init__`, `Thread.__init__` has "`daemon`" for input parameter.
I don't have any idea why it doesn't work...

Comment: Are there any other statements in your code?  Why are you making the thread a *daemon* thread?  If you have no other statements, python will exit if only `daemon` threads are left, and your thread will never have time to execute.

Comment: @BrendanAbel There are many threads  :) Thank u!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find the source code of that `threading.Thread()` constructor [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L1143) (of cpython, the most common python implementation):

```
def __init__(self, interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.interval = interval
    self.function = function
    self.args = args if args is not None else []
    self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
    self.finished = Event()
```

If you pass `daemon=True` into it, that will be put in `kwargs`, but as you can see in the code, nothing happens with it. So yes, you're correct, you'll have to set the `daemon` attribute after creating it (and **before** calling `start()`. There seems to be no option to set it directly when constructing the `Timer`.

Comment: No, the `daemon` argument will not be put in kwargs, because kwargs here is a single keyword argument, and not a double-star catcher. What happens when passing daemon=True is a TypeError.